# github actions | get origin branch on push

Tags: github, github-actions

I want that a workflow that starts on push will print the origin (base) branch name and name of the one who did the push.

for example if my name is Tom and I merged 'test' branch to master, I will be able to get 'Tom' and 'test' as values on the workflow that starts on push (right after the pull request).
I did find something that works on pull request to get the base branch name: `${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}`, but when replacing 'pull_request' with push it doesn't work anymore.
Is there a way to do it?
I've been searching for hours now and can't find a proper solution, for each type of event there is a different solution.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following properties of the [`github` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context):

- `github.ref_name`
- `github.event.pusher.name` (see: [`push` event payload](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push))

*Here is an example of a complete workflow:*

```
name: show-push-info

on:
  push:

jobs:
  print-info:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    
      - name: Print info
        run: echo "'${{ github.ref_name }}' was pushed by '${{ github.event.pusher.name }}'"
```

Comment: Hi @Matt thank you so much for your response.
The name of the pusher works great but the name of the branch shows 'master' and I intended to get the origin branch (in the example 'test'). Do you know any relevant property?